pmtiles command not recognized after global installation on Windows
I recently installed the pmtiles package globally using npm on my Windows machine, but when I try to run pmtiles -v in the command prompt, I get the following error:
 C:\Users\User>pmtiles -v 'pmtiles' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I followed these steps:

Installed the pmtiles package globally using the following command: Copy code npm install -g pmtiles After installation, I tried running pmtiles -v to check the version. Despite the global installation showing success when I run npm list -g pmtiles, I can't seem to access the pmtiles command in the terminal.


What I have tried so far:
Verified that pmtiles is installed globally by checking the npm list -g pmtiles  output.
Checked if the npm global path is correctly set in the environment variables.
Can someone help me figure out why this isn't working and how to resolve this?
System Info:
OS: Windows 10
Node.js version: 20.17.0
npm version: 9.7.2
This approach provides a clear and concise description of the problem while including the necessary details like steps taken, the specific error message, and system information.
